# Eclipse Updating a long range of data

Tags: android, sdk

Hye! I just downloaded eclipse Juno with the ADT plugin. Then I started the SDK manager and began to update !

It updated Android SDK tool to 23.0.5, Android SDK Platform tool to 21, Android SDK build tool to 20 and Android 5.0(API 21).

Alongside these, just two or three Extras got updated. But how could this be over 10 GB ? I have never seen SDK been updated for over 10GB. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably also downloaded a bunch of system images for virtual devices (aka Emulator). Each of those are around 500mb

Comment: Actually this is what I did. Can you tell me how to get rid of these redundant updates ? I need some space free on my hard drive. :)

Comment: I mean, I can delete those packages, thats alright. But which one should be deleted ? All the system images ? Would it affect anything ?

Comment: The "system images" are only necessary if you going to use the emulator. If you'll use your own device, you can delete all of them